# Vector3 deserialize problem

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I found a strange problem with my robot running ROS on UDOO board. The cmd_vel published by teleop is subscribed by Arduino sketch that drive motors according to received speed. Arduino and ROS communicate using rosserial python node. When a cmd_vel is published with positive speed all works fine. Sending negative speed result in robot moving at smallest speed in back direction. After some test I found the problem on Vector3 message in Arduino ros_lib: deserialize method fails with negative float (I receive -0.0000 instead -0.200). I'm sure the published  message is correct since using `rostopic echo /cmd_vel` print the right values.

At the end I success to make it works adding delays in deserialize method:

```
virtual int deserialize(unsigned char *inbuffer)
    {
      int offset = 0;
      uint32_t * val_x = (uint32_t*) &(this->x);
      offset += 3;
      *val_x = ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++))>>5 & 0x07);
      *val_x |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++)) & 0xff)<<3;
      *val_x |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++)) & 0xff)<<11;
      *val_x |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset)) & 0x0f)<<19;
      uint32_t exp_x = ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++))&0xf0)>>4;
      exp_x |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset)) & 0x7f)<<4;
      if(exp_x !=0)
        *val_x |= ((exp_x)-1023+127)<<23;
      delay(1);
      if( ((*(inbuffer+offset++)) & 0x80) > 0) this->x = -this->x;
      uint32_t * val_y = (uint32_t*) &(this->y);
      offset += 3;
      *val_y = ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++))>>5 & 0x07);
      *val_y |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++)) & 0xff)<<3;
      *val_y |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++)) & 0xff)<<11;
      *val_y |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset)) & 0x0f)<<19;
      uint32_t exp_y = ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++))&0xf0)>>4;
      exp_y |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset)) & 0x7f)<<4;
      if(exp_y !=0)
        *val_y |= ((exp_y)-1023+127)<<23;
      delay(1);
      if( ((*(inbuffer+offset++)) & 0x80) > 0) this->y = -this->y;
      uint32_t * val_z = (uint32_t*) &(this->z);
      offset += 3;
      *val_z = ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++))>>5 & 0x07);
      *val_z |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++)) & 0xff)<<3;
      *val_z |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++)) & 0xff)<<11;
      *val_z |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset)) & 0x0f)<<19;
      uint32_t exp_z = ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset++))&0xf0)>>4;
      exp_z |= ((uint32_t)(*(inbuffer + offset)) & 0x7f)<<4;
      if(exp_z !=0)
        *val_z |= ((exp_z)-1023+127)<<23;
      delay(1);
      if( ((*(inbuffer+offset++)) & 0x80) > 0) this->z = -this->z;
     return offset;
    }
```

This is working now but I have no idea why delays are needed! I'm quite sure is as problem of Arduino but since I found this problem using ROS make sense to advertise the ROS community.

Thanks
Alessandro

UPDATE

Thanks to gvdhoorn! I manually fix the ros_lib since I'm still using hydro and now it works fine. Still I cannot understand why the delay make it works too...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204530/vector3-deserialize-problem/) by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-10**:
Good to hear that you solved it, but we don't normally close questions on ROS Answers. If an answer solved your issue, click the checkmark to the left of it to mark it as accepted. The question can remain open to allow others to comment on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but this might be related to [rosserial/issues/86](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/86) (which was fixed in [rosserial/pull/144](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/pull/144), but only on `indigo-devel`).

Are you running rosserial from debs, or have you built it from source? The debs perhaps don't include the necessary fixes.

---

Edit:

> Thanks to gvdhoorn! I manually fix the ros_lib since I'm still using hydro and now it works fine. Still I cannot understand why the delay make it works too..

You could also try and see whether you can build `rosserial` from source, that would allow you to run the newest version of `rosserial` under Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0